# Failure to scale in pyclipper - TypeError: 'Zero' object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, sympy, pyclipper

I've just come up against a `TypeError` I've not seen before and can't figure out why it's occurring. Googling for the error `TypeError: 'Zero' object is not iterable` returns no results. I've tested in python 2.7 and 3.5 and the error is the same in both cases.

Here's the MCVE:

```
from sympy.geometry.polygon import Polygon
import pyclipper as pc

start_list = [(0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]
scaled = pc.scale_to_clipper(start_list)  # this works fine

as_poly = Polygon(*start_list)
new_list = [(pt.x, pt.y) for pt in as_poly.vertices]
assert new_list == start_list  # check that the lists are the same (this passes)

fail_to_scale = pc.scale_to_clipper(new_list)  # this fails
```

And the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jamie\<blah>\mcve.py", line 10, in <module>
    fails = pc.scale_to_clipper(new_list)
  File "pyclipper/pyclipper.pyx", line 544, in pyclipper.scale_to_clipper (pyclipper/pyclipper.cpp:3535)
  File "pyclipper/pyclipper.pyx", line 542, in pyclipper.scale_to_clipper.scale_value (pyclipper/pyclipper.cpp:3454)
  File "pyclipper/pyclipper.pyx", line 542, in pyclipper.scale_to_clipper.scale_value (pyclipper/pyclipper.cpp:3454)
  File "pyclipper/pyclipper.pyx", line 542, in pyclipper.scale_to_clipper.scale_value (pyclipper/pyclipper.cpp:3416)
TypeError: 'Zero' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know what the source of and solution to this error could be?

Comment: Does the assertion pass or fail? Are there any more lines of codes between the assignment to `new_list` and `fail_to_scale`? Prolly `new_list` was modified

Comment: The assertion passes, and that exact MCVE produces the error. There's no additional code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This has been fixed in PyClipper version 1.0.2, which is preferable to using the workaround described below**

Ok, I've tracked the problem back to the values stored in `Polygon`. The issue is that the value `0` is stored by SymPy as `sympy.Zero`.

These `sympy.Zero` values are not accepted by `polyclipper.scale_to_clipper()` and so are raising the `TypeError` when checked.

To avoid the issue I can generate `new_list` casting `pt.x` and `pt.y` to `float`:

```
new_list = [(float(pt.x), float(pt.y)) for pt in as_poly.vertices]
```

Comment: As you have already figured out - the problem is `pyclipper` thinks `sym.Zero` is a collection. This is a bug in the library. While this is getting fixed conversion of `sym.Zero` to `int` or `float` (it gets converted to C++ double anyway ) seems like a valid solution.

Comment: An update: a new version of pyclipper was released that fixes this problem.